# Преобразование строки в переменную

Tags: php

Суть такая. У меня есть tpl-файл, в котором содержится текст. Я этот файл включаю в php-код посредством функции `file();` Всё работает. Начинаю построчный вывод этого файла - тоже работает. Теперь мне нужен небольшой парсер, который при обнаружении специальной конструкции будет её заменять на другой текст. Вот текст tpl-файла

```
[php]peremena[/php]
```

Собственно сам php-код:

```
$peremena = 33; //переменная для замены

$php_codes = array( //собственно сами условия замены
    "\[php\](.+)\[/php\]" => "$1"
);

$tpl_file = file('page.general.tpl'); //подгрузка файла

foreach ($tpl_file as $line_num => $line){ //построчный вывод файла
    foreach ($php_codes as $key => $php_code) //сам парсер
        $line = preg_replace("#".$key."#isU", $$php_code, $line); //замена текста на переменную, имя которой содержится в $php_code

    echo $line; //вывод строки
}
```

В данном примере я добиваюсь замены текста `[php]peremena[/php]` на значение переменной `$peremena` - 33. Я понял, что переменная `$php_code` содержит текст `"$1"`, который функцией `preg_replace();` выполняет замену ключа на текст `peremena`. Но мне нужно, что этот текст был выведен программно, как переменная, чтоб подставить туда значения переменной с этим именем. Как это сделать?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php

*вы просто набор bad practice*

Comment: Честно - не могу понять, как эта функция может мне помочь. Она просто вызывает анонимную функцию при обнаружении совпадения, а мне нужно что это совпадение заменялось переменной.

---
Я нашёл решение проблемы, но оно не очень эстетичное, и в некоторых моментах может даже быть нерабочим. :(

Comment: она не просто вызывает, а вызывает ее с параметром в  виде найденных строк. 

но вам действительно это вряд-ли поможет, потому что вы по какой-то неведомой причине используете переменные вместо массива, сделайте массив и тогда, вы хотя-бы сможете ссылку на него передавать в эту функцию.

Comment: вот так примерно можно http://ideone.com/veaERl

Comment: Чёрт побери! А работает-то. Спасибо вам огромное. На данном этапе я решил одну проблему.
P.S.: почему вы ответы пишете в комментариях, а не в виде ответа? Разве вам это в плюс не пойдёт?

Comment: я же не могу прям переменную передать, ну а функцию... у вас там парсер  не правильный вот что я вам скажу,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php

можно передать параметром массив переменных, но не саму переменную, примерно так:

```
<?php
$vars=array();

$vars['peremena'] = 33; //переменная для замены
$vars['code'] = 'smart'; //переменная для замены

$php_codes = array( //собственно сами условия замены
    "\[php\](.+)\[/php\]" => "$1"
);

$tpl_file = [
'Hello [php]peremena[/php], ',
'Bye [php]code[/php] code'
];

$myMatch=function($match) use ($vars) {
        return $vars[$match[1]];
};

foreach ($tpl_file as $line_num => $line){ //построчный вывод файла
    foreach ($php_codes as $key => $php_code) //сам парсер
        $line = preg_replace_callback("#".$key."#isU", $myMatch, $line); //замена текста на переменную, имя которой содержится в $php_code

    echo $line; //вывод строки
}
```

Comment: Цитата:

    у вас там парсер не правильный вот что я вам скажу

Скажу честно - парсер сам писал, поэтому я сам знаю, что он "того".

Может посоветуете чего? Где мануалы курить? А то вздумалось мне движок сайта с нуля написать, так что теперь не отстану от этой идеи. Вчера с классами разобрался, сегодня, с вашей помощью, смог вызывать переменные.

Comment: надо теорию написания парсеров/интерпритаторов  читать, я сам если честно этим  никогда не занимался всерьез (не считая парсеров логов и прочего) посмотрите как сделаны какие-нибудь  шаблонизаторы,  типа https://github.com/bzick/fenom заодно поймете, что это не очень простая затея :)

Comment: @eicto спасибо. Кстати, тот метод, что вы предложили мне очень помог, но есть один момент - если у меня такая ситуация:

    $vars['peremena'] = array('name' => 'Василий', 'age' => 67);
То тут уж ничем не вытянешь сведения из массива. Будет надпись `Array`. Я в случаях написания такого текста в tpl-файле:

    [php]peremena['name'][/php]
        или
    [php]{peremena}['name'][/php]
        и т.д.
То в таких случаях вообще ничего не выведется, так как он не находит нужные перемены. :)

Что жаль, вообще-то. Ладно. Буду дальше читать. Спасибо вам ещё раз.

Comment: ну так все-же просто, делайте парсер квадратных скобок (можно из своего-же парсера, так сказать рекурсивно) и в случае, если match[1] не просто строка, то запускайте парсер еще раз, $vars в этом случае станет $vars['peremena'], я же говорю - шаблонизатор сложно писать. да и не нужно, тысячи их уже есть.

Comment: @eicto я вот чего не могу понять. В функции мы получаем значение переменной `$match[1]`. Как это значение в переменную изначально принимается, и при каких условиях появится переменная `$match[2]`?

---
Да, вы правы. В той игре используется Smarty. Правда я особо туда не лез. Уж очень он меня испугал, по крайней мере в работающем виде.

Comment: думаю вторая группа захвата. $match[0] - всё попадание, $match[1] - первая группа. итд.  в той игре наверное использовался smarty.

Comment: @eicto Я вам обязан огромным облегчением! Понимаете, я-то думал, что разработчики игры сами писали шаблонизатор. Я никогда и не думал, что Smarty, это отдельный шаблонизатор. Сейчас скачал его, установил, и сделал всё то, чего добивался вот этим кодом, который описан выше. Хотя наука для меня тоже неплохая. Я пока писал всё это, множество иных функций изучил. Теперь я могу спокойно продолжать писать свой движок, не заморачиваясь с шаблонизатором. Даже с массивами всё нормально - определяются без проблем. Огромное вам спасибо! Мне и парсер нужен был, чтоб использовать свои шаблоны. :)